# Freeswitch pauses on check_ip at boot on centos 7.1

Tags: linux, centos, admin, voip, freeswitch

During an investigation into a different problem ([Inconsistent systemd startup of freeswitch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33298818/1642105)) I discovered that both the latest freeswitch 1.6 and 1.7 paused for several minutes at a time (between 4 and 14) during boot up on centos 7.1. Whilst it was intermittent, it was as often as one time in 3 or 4.

Running this from the command line :

> ```
> /usr/bin/freeswitch -nonat -db /dev/shm -log /usr/local/freeswitch/log -conf /usr/local/freeswitch/conf -run /usr/local/freeswitch/run
> ```

caused the following output (note the time difference between the Add task 2 and the line after it) :

> ```
> 2015-10-23 15:40:14.160101 [INFO] switch_event.c:685 Activate Eventing Engine.
> 2015-10-23 15:40:14.170805 [WARNING] switch_event.c:656 Create additional event dispatch thread 0
> 2015-10-23 15:40:14.272850 [INFO] switch_core_sqldb.c:3381 Opening DB
> 2015-10-23 15:40:14.282317 [INFO] switch_core_sqldb.c:1693 CORE Starting SQL thread.
> 2015-10-23 15:40:14.285266 [NOTICE] switch_scheduler.c:183 Starting task thread
> 2015-10-23 15:40:14.293743 [DEBUG] switch_scheduler.c:249 Added task 1 heartbeat (core) to run at 1445611214
> 2015-10-23 15:40:14.293837 [DEBUG] switch_scheduler.c:249 Added task 2 check_ip (core) to run at 1445611214
> 2015-10-23 15:49:47.883158 [NOTICE] switch_core.c:1386 Created ip list rfc6598.auto default (deny)
> ```

When I ran it from 1.6 on centos6.7 using the same command line as above I got this - note the delay is a more reasonable 14 seconds :

> ```
> 2015-10-23 10:31:00.274533 [INFO] switch_event.c:685 Activate Eventing Engine.
> 2015-10-23 10:31:00.285807 [WARNING] switch_event.c:656 Create additional event dispatch thread 0
> 2015-10-23 10:31:00.434780 [INFO] switch_core_sqldb.c:3381 Opening DB
> 2015-10-23 10:31:00.465158 [INFO] switch_core_sqldb.c:1693 CORE Starting SQL thread.
> 2015-10-23 10:31:00.481306 [DEBUG] switch_scheduler.c:249 Added task 1 heartbeat (core) to run at 1445610660
> 2015-10-23 10:31:00.481446 [DEBUG] switch_scheduler.c:249 Added task 2 check_ip (core) to run at 1445610660
> 2015-10-23 10:31:00.481723 [NOTICE] switch_scheduler.c:183 Starting task thread
> 2015-10-23 10:31:14.286702 [NOTICE] switch_core.c:1386 Created ip list rfc6598.auto default (deny)
> ```

It's the same on FS 1.7 as well.

This suggests heavily that centos 7.1 & FS have an issue together. Can anyone help me diagnose further or shine some more light on this, please?

This all came to light as I tried to understand why FS would not accept the cli connection for several minutes after I thought it had booted up (using -nc from systemd service).

Comment: Do you know what `check_ip` is doing? Are you sure this is a CentOS 7 issue and not an issue with the configuration on your machine and/or your local network for that machine?

Comment: No i don't, and no I'm not. The source to check_ip seems to show it trying to resolve hostnames, and the output from FS seems to suggest it is being called from the scheduler. The two machines I am using to test this are Digital Ocean "droplets",one fired with 6.7and one with 7.1. Apart from installing freeswitch using a script of mine (identical on both) they are "as is". I would have thought a plain config issue would be present on both. If they can be different I don't know how. Could you suggest a test to see if resolving is causing an issue? Pinging seems fast enough.

Comment: I do agree that check_ip throws itself into the spotlight as prime suspect, but I'm uncertain on how to verify what the difference is between the two boxes that would make 6.7 work and 7.1 fail.

Comment: Does this delay repeat each time your reboot the droplet? Or just happen once? If you stick your own script into the boot sequence that does the same resolving steps do you see a similar delay? Do you see that delay if you just restart the service on a running droplet?

Comment: It happens 1 time in 3 or 4. So sometimes it will boot up within seconds, and others it will pause always at that point. I have noticed no correlation to rebooting the droplet (ie it appears to happen after a reboot and continues to happen 1 time in 3 or 4. I am running this from the command line which is the recommended way to test that FS and its config. are working. This is not being started from a systemd/init.d service yet, though that appears to fail in the same way. I don't have my own script as such (other than to fetch & build FS).

Comment: ...ran out of letters. I can ctl-c when its in the paused state to stop the boot, and running it again afterwards has the same 1 in 3-4 chance of pausing again.

Comment: Do you know what addresses it is trying to resolve? Can you try resolving them yourself? Does doing that hit the same delay? What DNS servers are set up on the two machines? Do they differ?

Comment: It doesn't tell me which host names it's trying to resolve in any output or log that I can find. Both boxes use Google's DNS (8.8.8.8 +  8.8.4.4). Is there a way to snoop on what it's trying to resolve, like a wireshark trace? Does resolving happen on a certain port or something liek that that I can snoop on? Any domains i try and resolve manually seem fine.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/93195/discussion-between-etan-reisner-and-beigerac).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the FS userlist and ultimately Anthony Minessale, the issue was to do with RNG entropy.

This is a good explanation -
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-additional-entropy-for-cloud-servers-using-haveged

Here are some extracts :

> There are two general random devices on Linux: /dev/random and
>   /dev/urandom. The best randomness comes from /dev/random, since it's a
>   blocking device, and will wait until sufficient entropy is available
>   to continue providing output.

The key here is that it's a blocking device, so any program waiting for a random number from /dev/random will pause until sufficient entropy is available for a "safe" random number.

This is a headless server, so the usual sources of entropy such as mouse/keyboard activity (and many others) do not apply. Thus the delays,

The fix is this :

> Based on the HAVEGE principle, and previously based on its associated
>   library, haveged allows generating randomness based on variations in
>   code execution time on a processor......(google the rest!)

Install like this :

```
yum install haveged
```

and start it up like this :

```
haveged -w 1024
```

making sure it restarts on reboot :

```
chkconfig haveged on
```

Hope this helps someone.

Comment: Nailed it! Thanks :D